# Printing return value from function in Perl

Tags: perl

How come the following works?

```
    print "Property is :" . $property->name("NODE_HOST") . "\n";
```

but not this:

```
    print "Property is : $property->$name("NODE_HOST")\n";
```

The compiler complains about the second snippet:

```
    Bareword found where operator expected at ./testProperties.pl line 11, near ""Property is : $property->$name("NODE_HOST"
    (Missing operator before NODE_HOST?)
```

Perl is normally pretty easy-going about taking shortcuts when printing out combinations of strings and variables. `$property->name` is a call to a class Property which returns the value of the name passed in:

```
    sub name {
       my ( $self, $propertyName ) = @_;
       my $hash_ref = $self->{_hashref};
       my %properties = %$hash_ref;
       my $property = $properties{$propertyName};
       return $property;
    }
```

Comment: As a side note, your `sub name` can be simplified. Get rid of `%properties and $property` and just access hashref element directly: `return $hash_ref->{$propertyName};`. Or even get rid of `$hash_ref` and do `return $self->{_hashref}->{$propertyName};`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because

```
print "Property is :" . $property->name("NODE_HOST") . "\n";
```

is properly quoted whereas:

```
print "Property is : $property->$name("NODE_HOST")\n";
```

is not. It means:

```
print "Property is : $property->$name("
NODE_HOST
")\n";
```

Which is a nonsensical statement.

When you use  `"` to start a quote, any following `"` means end of quote. You can't expect perl to understand that a non-escaped double quote is not intended as end of quote.

What you might have meant is

```
print "Property is : $property->$name(\"NODE_HOST\")\n";
```

But that wont do what you expect.

I assume that the reason for trying to interpolate here is that it is awkward to keep opening and closing quotes. You have some options:

```
printf "Property is: %s\n", $property->name("NODE_HOST");

$name = $property->name("NODE_HOST");
print "Property is: $name\n";

use v5.10; # to enable say()
say "Property is: ", $property->name("NODE_HOST");
```

Or if you have a list of statements to print, it might be easiest to store them in an array, and then print them, e.g.:

```
push @props, "Property#1 is: " . $property->name("NODE_HOST");
push @props, "Property#2 is: " . $property->name("FOO");
...
say for @props;   # print them all
```

Comment: You won’t get a function call retval interpolated that easily.

Answer (score 3):

Perl does NOT interpolate subroutine calls in `""`. It ONLY interpolates scalar and array variables. You can read the gory details of interpolation rules on [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Gory-details-of-parsing-quoted-constructs).

You CAN however do a scalar expression:

```
print "Property is : ${ \( $property->name('NODE_HOST') ) }\n";
```

However, truth be told, it's highly un-readable and I would advise STRONGLY against it. Just do the boring:

```
my $property_name = $property->name('NODE_HOST');
print "Property is : $property_name\n";

# or    

print "Property is :" . $property->name("NODE_HOST") . "\n";
```

Comment: That doesn't quite work.  You need `"foo ${ \scalar func() } bar"` or `"foo @{ [ func() ] } bar"`.  This is all known tech; been documented since the beginning of time.

Comment: @tchrist - Duh. Should have actually LOOKED at the cookbook first ;)

Comment: No such thing as a list variable.

Answer (score 0):

You've got unescaped quotes inside quotes. `NODE_HOST` is outside any string.